# Получение значение char'а из памяти

Tags: c++, память, c++builder, char

мне нужно получить 16-ричное значение элемента массива чаров из памяти, проблема в том что надо получать и 0 и значения у которых нет значений в ASCII FF например.
ЯП c++

Comment: Ну так выводите его кодом, в чём проблема?

Comment: Если байт FF или наподобии, то в c++ билдере  вот так b += IntToStr(static_cast<int>(rer[i])) выдает -112 и другие отрицательные

Comment: на 16 ричное 0x90 выдает -112, это потому что у него нет чаркода и по большому счету это код намлока, но мне надо получить 10-ричную интерпритацию 0x90, т.е. 144

Comment: Приводите сначала к `unsigned char` а не к `int`.

Comment: Спасибо, сам не догадался.

Comment: *"0x90 выдает -112, это потому что у него нет чаркода"* Дело не в этом. Что вообще значит *"нет чаркода"*? Дело в том, что у `0x90` восьмой бит - единица, и когда вы засовываете его в знаковый `char`, то этот восьмой бит становится битом знака.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat хотите расскажу, что это значит: это значит, что я не знал, по-этому спросил, ведь если бы знал, то не спрашивал.

Comment: По комментарию создалось впечатление, что вы считаете, что знаете причину. В любом случае, теперь знаете. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается вот так `b = (unsigned int)((unsigned char)rer[i]);` , в результате получается 10-ричное значение шестнадцатеричного значение пмяти чара, всем спасибо. Перевод в hex через IntToHex.